# How to convert iter.take() to Vec<T> or to &[T]?

Tags: rust, vector, iterator

I have a struct called `Cell`:

```
pub struct Cell {
    x: X, // Some other struct
    y: Y, // Some other struct
    weight: usize,
}
```

I was trying to select the top preference cell out of some `Row` (a collection of `Cell`s):

```
// Return the top n-matching cells with a positive weight
pub fn select_preference(&mut self) -> Vec<Cell> {
    let top = 3;

    self.sort();
    // After sorting, omit the cells with weight = 0
    // And select the top preference cells
    self.cells.split(|cell| cell.weight() == 0).take(top)
}
```

However, I am getting an expected error actually:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:35:9
   |
29 |     pub fn select_preference(&mut self) -> Vec<Cell> {
   |                                            --------- expected `Vec<Cell>` because of return type
...
35 |         self.cells.split(|cell| cell.weight() == 0).take(top)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Vec`, found struct `std::iter::Take`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Vec<Cell>`
              found struct `std::iter::Take<std::slice::Split<'_, Cell, [closure@src/lib.rs:35:26: 35:32]>>`
```

I don't know how to convert the `Take` into `Vec<Cell>` or `&[Cell]`. I know the `Take` is some sort of `Iterator` but I'm unable to convert it.

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&code=type%20X%20%3D%20u32%3B%0Atype%20Y%20%3D%20u32%3B%0A%0Apub%20struct%20Cell%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20X%2C%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%20Y%2C%0A%20%20%20%20weight%3A%20usize%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Cell%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20weight(%26self)%20-%3E%20usize%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.weight%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20struct%20Row%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20cells%3A%20Vec%3CCell%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Row%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20sort(%26mut%20self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.cells%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.sort_by(%7Clighter%2C%20heavier%7C%20heavier.weight().cmp(%26lighter.weight()))%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Return%20the%20top%20n-matching%20cells%20with%20a%20positive%20weight%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20select_preference(%26mut%20self)%20-%3E%20Vec%3CCell%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20top%20%3D%203%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.sort()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20After%20sorting%2C%20omit%20the%20cells%20with%20weight%20%3D%200%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20And%20select%20the%20top%20preference%20cells%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.cells.split(%7Ccell%7C%20cell.weight()%20%3D%3D%200).take(top)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%7D)

Comment: Does `collect`ing the iterator work? This can be used to place all the elements of an iterator into a container such as a vector. A minimum working example would be helpful here.

Comment: @frankplow, the `collect` requires me to implement the `FromIterator`, which I believe isn't the idiomatic way. I added a Rust Playground link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `split` is probably not what you want -- that creates an iterator where each element is a block of nonzero items. You probably want `.iter().filter(|cell| cell.weight() != 0)`: iterate over elements of the vector, then filter out those that are nonzero.

To return a vector from an iterator, you need `.collect()`. However, this would give a `Vec<&Cell>` -- which doesn't quite match your function signature. Since you want a `Vec<Cell>`, you also need to clone the elements first to get new cells -- so you can use `.cloned()` first. That requires adding `#[derive(Clone)]` to `Cell`. This is the end result:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Cell {
    x: X,
    y: Y,
    weight: usize,
}

// Return the top n-matching cells with a positive weight
pub fn select_preference(&mut self) -> Vec<Cell> {
    let top = 3;

    self.sort();
    // After sorting, omit the cells with weight = 0
    // And select the top preference cells
    self.cells.iter().filter(|cell| cell.weight() != 0).take(top).cloned().collect()
}
```

As a general rule, it's common to always derive `Clone` for structs of data.

Other designs are possible too -- you can return the `Vec<&Cell>` directly, as the other answer suggests. Finally, you could return an iterator instead of a `Vec`; here's how that looks:

```rust
pub fn select_preference(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &Cell> {
    let top = 3;

    self.sort();
    // After sorting, omit the cells with weight = 0
    // And select the top preference cells
    self.cells.iter().filter(|cell| cell.weight() != 0).take(top)
}
```

Comment: Another option is to use [`drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain) instead of `iter`, which avoids cloning but will remove the cells from `self.cells` (i.e. `self.cell` will be empty after the call): [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=2460c1ff1711f8defe0fce887557d9e2)

Comment: @Jmb true but probably not what the OP wants!

Answer (score 2):

Returning a vector of references to the relevant cells is, I think, the most idiomatic way to do this as it allows using iterators. You can then write:

```
pub fn select_preference(&mut self) -> Vec<&Cell> {
    let top = 3;
    self.sort();
    self.cells.iter().filter(|cell| cell.weight() != 0).take(top).collect()
}
```

You can even sort only the iterator and not the `Vec<Cell>` itself.

Returning a slice is difficult as a slice must always refer to a contiguous part of a sequence. This will always be the case here due to the sorting of `cells`, however the iterator methods don't take this into account and so cannot be used. One way you could do it is:

```rust
pub fn select_preference(&mut self) -> &[Cell] {
    let mut top = 3;
    self.sort();
    let mut ret = &self.cells[..cmp::min(self.cells.len(), top)];
    while ret[ret.len() - 1].weight() == 0 {
        ret = &ret[..ret.len() - 1];
    }
    ret
}
```

But it is probably evident that this is not very idiomatic Rust.

Comment: For the latter thing, you should also be able to do it with `split()`: `&self.cells.split(|cell| cell.weight() != 0).next().unwrap()[0..top]` -- but still not super advisable

Comment: @6005 There is a potential runtime error here as there may not be `top` elements in the unwrapped slice. This is why the `cmp::min` is used in my example above. You could do this with the `split` iterator approach also, but it all gets a bit fiddly as you need the length of the iterator (which requires cloning it and giving it a name).

Comment: Yep it's super fiddly :)